# Transfer character into numeric without losing accuracy

Tags: r

How to transfer a character class matrix into a numeric class matrix without losing accuracy in R?

The elements in the matrix is 10-16 digits after decimal point while function `as.numeric` can only transfer them into 8 digits after decimal point.

I searched this website and some of you said using `Rmpfr`,however it doesn't transfer the matrix into numeric.

Here expression0 is the matrix I want to transfer. `mpfr` is the function in package `Rmpfr` to transfer the character into numeric.

```
> expression0 <- mpfr(expression0, 200)
> class(expression0[1,1])
[1] "mpfr"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Rmpfr"
```

Here the class of the transformed matrix is still not numeric thus I cannot do operation like drawing a boxplot to the data.

Are there any other methods than `as.numeric` can help me achieve the effect?

Comment: what does your code have to do with this question? Which bit of data has 16 deciaml points? where are the ways you have tried/what is going wrong? What's mpfr/Rmpfr?

Comment: R doesn't always print everything that's there: `x <- 1/3; x; print(x, digits = 16)`

Comment: `as.numeric("1.123456789") - as.numeric("1.12345678")` does not return 0, suggesting it is not stopping at 8 digits. Further, `as.numeric("1.1234567890123456") - as.numeric("1.123456789012345")` is also not 0, though we are getting near limits of floating point accuracy, since it is returning `6.7e-16`. If you have larger numbers (10s, 100s, etc), then this level may change. More information here will help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

All the digits are there, they're just not printed by default:

```
print(as.numeric("1.1234567890123456"),digits=17)
[1] 1.1234567890123457
```